# WPF MVVM Databinding - Check for space and then clear the checkbox

Tags: wpf, binding, mvvm, textbox

im kind of new to using the MVVM patter on my WPF application and i have stumbled into a strange situation. Im actually trying to make something similar to the Metainputtextbox here on StackOverflow (when your writing a new question).

So what im trying to do:

I have a textbox (doh!) and binding it to a property in my viewModel. 
On the set property im checking for a space (' ') if there is a space but its not empty (meaning there is a metaword in there) i trim it from spaces and saves it to my private property. And calls the updateProp. Now here comes the tricky part. After the metaword is saved i want to clear the string and textbox but setting my property to "" will of course trigger the whole thing around again.

XAML

```
<TextBox 
         Name="txtBoxMetaInput" 
         Text="{Binding Path=MetaInput, Mode=TwoWay,
         UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

viewModel

```
    private string metaInput { get; set; }
    public string MetaInput 
    {
        get {  return metaInput; }
        set 
        {
            if (value.Contains(' ') && String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) == false)
            {
                metaInput = value.Trim(' ');
                saveTheMetaKeyWordToAnArrayOfMetawords();
                this.OnPropertyChanged("MetaInput");
            }
        }
    }
```

Now whats missing there is that i want to empty the textbox and clear the property´s after saving it to the metaword array.

This problem probably just needs a new set of eyes on it  :)

Answer (score 1):

> Now here comes the tricky part. After the metaword is saved i want to clear the string and textbox but setting my property to "" will of course trigger the whole thing around again.

Just set the backing field (before raising PropertyChanged), not the property.  This will prevent the "retrigger" of the value.

Comment: Imean yeah i think thats works for the property and the handeling but it wont update the control...

Comment: @user1057806 It will - you just have to raise your PropertyChanged  for that property *when you're done*.  Right now, you're effectively raising it 2x - it only needs to be raised once at the end for the control to update.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is probably to use a value converter on the binding that converts from `string` to `string[]` and back again:

```
<local:TagConverter x:Key="TagConverter" />

<TextBox 
      Name="txtBoxMetaInput" 
      Text="{Binding Path=MetaInput, Mode=TwoWay,
      UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource TagConverter}}"/>
```

`TagConverter` is a class you write which implements `IValueConverter`. In `Convert` you convert from `string` to `string[]`, splitting on spaces. In `ConvertBack`, you join the `string[]` back to a `string`.

Comment: But this still wont clean the box for me? 
I mean the messy part aint the value coming in its actually to setting the parameter back to null and making the textbox react to that new null value.

Comment: Oh, do you want the text box to clear after entering each tag instead of keeping a list of tags in it?